# PayPalのIPN接続元IPについて

Tags: paypal

サーバを設定する際に、管理系の機能等にIP制限をかけています。
そこで、IPNの接続元のIPを知りたいのですが、どこかにのっていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

"こちらです。

本番環境
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92/ で下記を選択してください。
notify.paypal.com
ipnpb.paypal.com

Sandbox
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/250/ の下記です。
ipn.sandbox.paypal.com: 173.0.82.126
ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com: 173.0.82.66"